# Removing or replacing ascii null character <0x00> from column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way I can remove/replace the ascii null character <0x00> in snowflake?

```sql
SELECT 
   productname 
FROM 
   tableA
```

yields:

```
Bud Light<0x00>
```

when I review it in sublime.

I'm looking to yield just `Bud Light`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ASCII null, you can replace it like this:

```
select replace(PRODUCTNAME, chr(0), '') as PRODUCTNAME from tableA;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Greg has said, you can use the `trim` function which will remove the null characters from the beginning and end only.

**Example which you can run in a Snowflake workseet**

```sql
select 
   hex_decode_string('61626300') "4 char null terminated string", 
   len(hex_decode_string('61626300')) "Length before trim", 
   len(trim(hex_decode_string('61626300'), char('0'))) "Length after trim";
```

**Your example fixed**

```sql
SELECT 
   trim(productname, char('0')) 
FROM 
   tableA
```