# Snowflake hidden Ascii characters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have attached an image below with what my issue.
I have also looked at this:
[Removing or replacing ascii null character <0x00> from column in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471644/removing-or-replacing-ascii-null-character-0x00-from-column-in-snowflake)
AND
[Remove non-ASCII characters from a string in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368577/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-in-snowflake)
posts and implemented or tried the same around with my code .
NOW, on to my code .
I know the issue is this "internal" VW_QUERY_HISTORY view that came w/ Snowflake. I thought it was date issue BUT its NOT . I even went as far as doing UTC on dates in case Snowflake in its wisdom was using location time.
So any advice would be great; clearly I have wrapped and trimmed it enough.

```
select  RTRIM(replace(replace(a.Full_Table_Name, char(32), ''), char(13), ''),'  ') as Full_Table_Name
,RTRIM(replace(replace(TRIM(replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'TEST_DATABASE.DUMMY_SCHEMA.','' )), char(32), ''), char(13), ''),'  ') as Short_Table_Name_1
,log.TABLE_NAME as AUDIT_LOGGIN_TABLE_NAME
from (
  
  select  replace (replace(UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12)) , char(32), ''), char(13), '') as Full_Table_Name
  ,to_date(convert_timezone('UTC',START_TIME) ) as ETL_DATE
from  "TEST_DATABASE"."AUDIT_LOGGING"."VW_QUERY_HISTORY" as vw
where substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12) like '%DUMMY_SCHEMA%'
and QUERY_TYPE = 'COPY'
and UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))  like '%TEST_DATABASE.DUMMY_SCHEMA%'
 and to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-1,current_date() )
  
) as a
LEFT JOIN TEST_DATABASE.AUDIT_LOGGING.DUMMY_SCHEMA_SOURCE_TABLE_COUNTS as log  on replace (replace(UPPER(replace(UPPER(log.TABLE_NAME),'SCPOMGR.','')), char(13), ''), char(32), '') =  TRIM(regexp_replace(replace (replace(TRIM(replace(UPPER(Full_Table_Name),'TEST_DATABASE.DUMMY_SCHEMA.','' )), char(13), ''), char(32), ''), char(32), ''),char(32))
and log.ETL_Date = 20211207
// and a.ETL_DATE = convert_timezone('UTC', to_date(concat(substring(log.ETL_DATE,0,4),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,5,2),'-',substring(log.ETL_DATE,7,2) ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: I should also point out . . . LEFT JOIN TEST_DATABASE.AUDIT_LOGGING.DUMMY_SCHEMA_SOURCE_TABLE_COUNTS is my own table around this specific data mart where I log aggregate counts on deltas for that day's load . This is line 7 in the picture above.

Comment: I'm not following what your problem/issue is. I see the blanks and whatnot, but I'm not understanding what you are trying to solve for here. Your sql is thick and trying to thin it out so I can replicate is a chore. Do you have a minimal, verifiable and reproducible example or can you better explain what you are trying to pick out of your `COPY` statements in the query_history log and to what you are trying to join it to (perhaps some sample data and desired results would help?).

Comment: Also, I don't understand the relationship between your sql statement and your screenshot. There are many more columns in your screenshot than you are selecting in your SQL.

Comment: hi @JNevill , mainly I'm trying to join the "internal" Snowflake view called VW_QUERY_HISTORY to my table on table_name and date columns. It works fine on 16 of the 17 instances except this 1 case where even after removing 'spaces' I seem to have trailing spaces. Like I pointed out in my screenshot. Hence I dont get the table name OR record count (being a LEFT join) from my table .

Comment: Can you copy/paste as-is the tables you are pulling from the `COPY` statement into the question including the spaces that you are getting?

Comment: select  replace (replace(UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12)) , char(32), ''), char(13), '') as Full_Table_Name
  ,to_date(convert_timezone('UTC',START_TIME) ) as ETL_DATE
from  "VW_QUERY_HISTORY" as vw
where substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12) like '%JDA%'
and QUERY_TYPE = 'COPY'
and UPPER(substring(QUERY_TEXT,11,charindex('from',QUERY_TEXT)-12))  like '%RAW_TABLE_DB.JDA%'
 and to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-1,current_date()

Comment: Apologies. Busy day here. I'm still not 100% following, but I'm thinking you may just be better off hitting the `Query_text` with regex instead of traying to substring/charindex/replace/trim your way to the table name. Something like `REGEXP_REPLACE(Query_Text, '^.*COPY INTO (["0-9a-z._$]*).*$','\\1',1,1,'si')`

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out my recommendation. I think trying to parse SQL with `charindex`, `substring`, `replace`, etc will lead to a lot more edge cases than if attempt the parsing with regex instead.

I believe something like the following will get you in the ballpark:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(Query_Text, '^.*COPY INTO (["0-9a-z._$]*).*$','\\1',1,1,'si') as Full_Table_Name
    ,strtok(FULL_TABLE_NAME, '.', REGEXP_COUNT(Full_Table_Name, '[.]')+1) AS Short_table_name
    ,to_date(convert_timezone('UTC',START_TIME) ) as ETL_DATE
    ,query_Text
FROM  "TEST_DATABASE"."AUDIT_LOGGING"."VW_QUERY_HISTORY"
WHERE QUERY_TYPE = 'COPY'
  AND to_date(START_TIME) >= dateadd(day,-1,current_date() );
```

That `REGEXP_REPLACE` is capturing a string that is after `COPY INTO`  that contains any combination of the characters 0-9, a-z (case insensitive), a `.`, `_`, or `$` which are all of the allowed characters in an object name in Snowflake. It will stop capturing when it encounters any other character (space, or breaking space, or carriage return/line feed, etc). This is more fool proof since only the allowed characters will come through.

Same goes for your `Short_Table_Name` logic where I'm using `STRTOK()` to split the `Full_Table_Name` by periods and picking the last item from the split. Again using regex to get the count of the number of period characters and adding 1 (strtok is 1-based index).

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE gives the expected result . Thank you . Rep added .

Comment: So glad to hear that did the trick!